# Proper syntax for DeleteCases with conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

List is an array of dimensions {61777, 3}. 
dist1 & dist2 are RegionDistanceFunctions.

Using:

```
list2 = Union[
DeleteCases[listhex, {a_, b_, c_} /;dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 ||dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004],
Cases[listhex, {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, 0} /;dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004]
]
```

Works fine, I delete points near the region I want and then put them back as {x,y,0}.

Now I create two RotationTransforms:

```
R1 = RotationTransform[120/180*\[Pi], {0, 0, 1}];
R2 = RotationTransform[120/180*2 \[Pi], {0, 0, 1}];
```

I wanted to do the same thing by simply applying the transformation after the condition of dist1 & dist2  is used.

```
list3 = Union[
   DeleteCases[listhex, {a_, b_, c_} /;dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a,b}] < 0.004], 
   DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> R1[{a, b, c}] /; dist1[{a, b}] <0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004],
   DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> R2[{a, b, c}] /; dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004],
   Cases[listhex, {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, 0} /;dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004], 
   Cases[listhex, {a_, b_, c_} :> R1[{a, b, 0}] /; dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004|| dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004],
   Cases[listhex, {a_, b_, c_} :> R2[{a, b, 0}] /; dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004]
   ]
```

Now the part using Cases works fine, it gives the same points near the region only rotated by R1 or R2. However,DeleteCases doesnt work with R1 or R2.

```
Dimensions[DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} /; dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 ||dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004]]
Dimensions[DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> R1[{a, b, c}] /; dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004]]
Dimensions[DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> R2[{a, b, c}] /; dist1[{a, b}] < 0.004 || dist2[{a, b}] < 0.004]]

{61153, 3}
{61777, 3}
{61777, 3}
```

Why does this happen? I can delete the cases without the rotation but using the rotation does nothing, as you can see by the dimmensions of the array. 
What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand what the rule in `DeleteCases` should do: `DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} :> R1[{a, b, c}]`. There is no such syntax for `DeleteCases`, it just deletes what it finds, it doesn't replace it.

Comment: What I wanted to do was use the unrotated points as a guide to identify the points, but delete the rotated ones. I thought :> would hold the expression and use it as input for deletecases.

Comment: I see. Then perhaps something like: `DeleteCases[list, {a_, b_, c_} /; With[{{ra, rb, rc} = R[{a, b, c}]}, dist1[{ra, rb}] < 0.004 || dist2[{ra, rb}] < 0.004]]`? You can read `;` as "such that", in a way: "Delete those points from `list` of the form `{a, b, c}`, such that, with `{ra, rb, rc}` being the rotated points, the distances between the latter are..."

Comment: Wont that use the rotated points for the distance test? I need to check for distance using the original points and then delete the rotated ones.

Comment: Giovanni, I see what you mean now. I would still recommend against it: even though it may be possible to twist `DeleteCases` that way with some contortions, that's really now what it is for. It would also be inadvisable because you may not *find* the rotated points exactly in your list, because of slightly different rounding / numerical error between the points in the list and the points you calculated through rotation.

Comment: @MarcoB Any suggestions to remove these points?